# Lambdas in ternary operator unexpected behavior

Tags: python, lambda, ternary-operator

```
>>> (lambda: 1 if True else lambda: 2)()
1
>>> (lambda: 1 if False else lambda: 2)()
<function <lambda>.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f5772e8eef0>
>>> (lambda: 1 if False else lambda: 2)()()
2
```

Why does it require calling the latter one twice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing it like `lambda: 1 if condition else lambda: 2` will have it interpreted like this:

```
lambda: (1 if condition else lambda: 2)
```

You need to write it like this in order for it to work as intended:

```
(lambda: 1) if condition else lambda: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lambda: 1 if False else lambda: 2
```

Let me write this as a normal function with if-statements:

```
def func():
    if False:
        return 1
    else:
        return (lambda: 2)
```

Now if I do:

```
x = func()
```

`x` will be `lambda: 2` - which is another function.

So how do I get to the `2`?

```
x()
```

This gives:

```
2
```

Now if I in-line the variable `x`:

```
res = func()()
```

Now `res` will be `2`

I hope that was clear. That's why the two `()` was required.

You probably wanted something like this:

```
(lambda: 1) if False else (lambda: 2)
```

Which is just a normal if-statement returning functions.